# How do i use $1 to remove white spaces in regex using sublime?

Tags: arrays, regex, sublimetext3, removing-whitespace

My goal is to convert the list item below using Sublime:

```
green apple
red apple
yellow banana
```

Into this:

```
{"greenapple, "redapple", "yellowbanana"}
```

found the regex for the above as so:

```
^([a-z]+\s[a-z]+)$
```

I entered below and clicked replace all:

```
"$1",
```

output:

```
"green apple",
"red apple",
"yellow banana",
```

How do I remove the white space?

Comment: Try `^(\w+) (\w+)$` and `"$1$2",`

Comment: not sure why but i got ^(\w+) (\w+)$ and "" as the replace outputs respectively

Comment: maybe because sublime doesn't support `\w` I don't know but try the same with `^([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)$`

Comment: Why not *first* remove spaces, *then* convert to json? That also caters for any number of words.

Comment: yup, i figured to just use the strip() function using python and they did work. But i'm still exploring about regex and what I can do with it.

Comment: but nevertheless, thank you guys!

Comment: With a single regex, you can get `"green apple","red apple","yellow banana",` using `^([a-z]+\s[a-z]+)$\R?`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/AzFZmH/1). Since the comma is inserted after a match it is not quite possible to do what you ant without a conditional replacement.